# Typescript declarations not emitting custom typings directory

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a library in typescript, and have a node_modules dependency that doesn't have a corresponding @types definition, so I wrote my own.

I put it in a typings folder and mapped that in tsconfig, so all the references work in my library. When I compile it (with declaration = true in tsconfig), the definition is nowhere to be found and it breaks when importing from another project.

How do I get my custom node_modules definition to be exported in a way where the declarations are correct in my distributable?

My tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "./typings/*"
            ]
        },
        "outDir": "dist",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationDir": "dist/typings",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "inlineSourceMap": false,
        "inlineSources": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "pretty": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2015"
        ],
        "typeRoots": [
            "typings"
        ]
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "include": [
        "./src"
    ]
}
```

In my typings folder in the root of the project, I have

```
- typings
 - rc-slider
   - index.d.ts
```

contents of index.d.ts:

```
declare module "rc-slider" {
    import * as React from "react";

    export interface Marks {
...
    export default class Slider extends React.Component<SliderProps> {}
    export class Range extends React.Component<RangeProps> {}
    export class Handle extends React.Component<HandleProps> {}
}
```

In the file that consumes the rc-slider module, I have:

```
import RcSlider, {
    Range,
    Handle,
    SliderProps as RcSliderProps,
} from "rc-slider";

export interface SliderProps extends RcSliderProps {
...
export class Slider extends Component<SliderProps> {
    public render() {
        const { label, name, formState, ...sliderProps } = this.props;
        const hasError = formState.getError(this.props.name);
        let err;
        if (hasError) {
            err = hasError.detail || hasError.title;
        }
        const disabled =
            formState.disabled || formState.submitting || sliderProps.disabled;
        renderCss();
        return (
            <FormControl label={label} error={err}>
                <RcSlider {...sliderProps} disabled={disabled} />
            </FormControl>
        );
    }
}
```

Which is a Slider composed on top of it, that uses the same properties defined in the rc-slider definition I wrote. When I export the lib, the 
Slider.d.ts file contains:

```
import { Component } from "react";
import { Range, Handle, SliderProps as RcSliderProps } from "rc-slider";
import { FormState } from "./FormState";
export { Range, Handle, RcSliderProps };
export interface SliderProps extends RcSliderProps {
    label: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
    name: string;
    formState: FormState;
    onChange: (v: string) => void;
}
export declare class Slider extends Component<SliderProps> {
    render(): JSX.Element;
}
```

but the rc-slider is type 'any', is nowhere to be found and those props aren't usable when I import the library. How can I get typescript to export my defintion?

Thanks!

Comment: Please write a [MCVE]. Show us the declarations file, the package.json and tsconfig.json, and how you included the library in the consumer project.

Comment: @E_net4 updated with examples.